# How to run a report (or query) to get the number of (first) child records of a record?

Tags: reporting, query, object

Any way I can do this via report? or apex if not?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this query (it will have as sublist for each account 1 Withdrawal__c with the earliest CreatedDate):

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount__c FROM Withdrawals__r ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account
```

After querying it, you'll have:

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount__c FROM Withdrawals__r ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account];

Decimal totalAmountWithdrawn = 0;
for (Account acc : accs) {
    if (acc.Withdrawals__r.size() > 0 && acc.Withdrawals__r[0].Amount__c != null) {
        totalAmountWithdrawn += acc.Withdrawals__r[0].Amount__c;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user256515 Have updated the answer, your relationship is called: Withdrawal**s**__r, not Withdrawal__r.

Comment: Thank you, this does work! Unfortunately I'm hitting a "too many query rows error", is there any way to bypass this? https://i.imgur.com/omAfl3j.jpeg

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, you should limit account records, so there are 2 records per account (account + withdrawal). You can also limit query like this `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount__c FROM Withdrawals__r ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Withdrawal__c)`, so there will not be listed accounts with NO withdrawals.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

SELECT Id, (SELECT Amount__c FROM Withdrawal__r ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account where CreadtedDate = THIS_YEAR

And then iterate on the list to calculate total